# COM Reference count is always 2

Tags: c++, com

Good day.

I worked with COM last days and when I create an instance, reference count is always 2. I read some questions on this topic and frequent answer tells something about thread stuff. So I placed creating the COM object to the beginning of the program before creating any threads and count was 2 immediately after creating. I don't use any **QueryInterface**.

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_EventViewer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    IID_IEventViewer, (void**)&view);
int count = view->AddRef();
```

Comment: The reference count is not known to the client in COM.  The client just has to match AddRef and Release calls (etc.) Where are you getting 2 from?

Comment: I obtained this value as return from AddRef and MSDN says that return value of AddRef is new reference count so I expected value 1.

Comment: MSDN actually says that the return value of AddRef is not reliable and should only be used for test purposes

Comment: We need a [mcve] to see what is happening.  How are you creating the object?  `CoCreateInstance` will return a pointer with a reference count of 1.  If you call `AddRef` on that pointer, the reference count will become 2.

Comment: So this value don't tell about reality of reference count and should be for example 45?

Comment: Martin Bonner, you are right.

Comment: Please do not rely on the return value of `AddRef`.  It works for trivial objects, but if an object implements rarely-used, heavy-weight interfaces by creating another sub-object behind the scenes, then AddRef may only reflect the reference count of the sub-object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `CoCreateInstance`, that returns a pointer with a reference count already established.  (You eventually need to call `Release` to free it.)

When you call `AddRef`, you *increase* the reference count (to 2).  Why are you calling `AddRef` immediately after creating the object?

Comment: I maintained a tool and I see this pattern always used in the code so I assumed something like, this is convention. Thank you.

Comment: That *sounds* like a recipe for a memory leak - but without seeing the whole code it's hard to be sure.  The convention may well include double calls to Release too - for example:  CoCreate local variable, AddRef + copy to member variable, Release local variable, eventually Release member.  That would be sensible.